# How to get different sized elements to fit neatly together using css grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid using css. The first element has a fixed height which is causing the whole first row to have the same height. I want the elements in the second row to push up and fill the empty space in the first row. Is there anyway of achieving this with css grid?[image: The grid]

The page I'm intending to using this for will have elements that will change in size depending on what the user submits.

I've tried using grid-auto-columns and grid-auto-rows along with grid-auto-flow: dense; but i can't get any combination of these to get the desired result. Any advice appreciated.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

body {
  background-color: #3b404e;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1EAAFC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
}

.item1 {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen I am practicing on:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/mozilladevelopers/pen/eGdQRN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as adding:

```
.primary {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

Though obviously I chose to add a CSS class to the element you want to have focus, in order to do so:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

body {
  background-color: #3b404e;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1EAAFC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
}

.item1 {
  height: 250px;
}

.primary {
  /* this causes the .primary element(s) to expand across
     two of the grid-row tracks: */
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1 primary"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v3ay7tu1/).

The above could, of course, be achieved without adding a class-name and simply specifying an `:nth-child()` element:

```
/* or .container > div:first-child: */
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

body {
  background-color: #3b404e;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1EAAFC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
}

.item1 {
  height: 250px;
}

/* or .container > div:first-child: */
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1 primary"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v3ay7tu1/1).

References:

- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).

Answer (score 0):

first thing you can't with only 2 rows. Grid gives a structure.

with 3 rows, it's possible

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

body {
  background-color: #3b404e;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1EAAFC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
}

.item1 {
  height: 250px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.item5 {
  height: 250px;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.item6 {
  height: 250px;
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="item item6"></div>
</div>
```

This is one way to do it with grid-area position for each item

It's also possible to do same with span

Answer (score 0):

Another manner to solve this issue...

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

body {
  background-color: #3b404e;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1EAAFC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
}

.item1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    height: 250px;
}
.item4 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
        
}
.item5 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item item3">item 3</div>
  <div class="item item4">item 4</div>
  <div class="item item5">item 5</div>
  </div>
```